# How to override Add to cart functionality in Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2.2, overrides, custom, addtocart

How to override Add to cart functionality in `Magento 2.2` using custom extension?

Comment: what override you want?

Comment: When I add a product to the cart and if the product is part of grouped product then the product image in the cart should be the base image of that grouped product.