# Magento 2 : How to override price functionality on cart

Tags: magento2.3, shopping-cart-price-rules, mini-cart

Want to override cart price display functionality.
Want to apply some additional formula before displaying Price on the cart and mini cart.
Can anyone tell me how can I achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance..!

[image]
[image]

[How to override Add to cart functionality in Magento 2.2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/245309/how-to-override-add-to-cart-functionality-in-magento-2-2)

Answer (score 0):

**1**. If you want small changes in price you should use **event**

> checkout_cart_product_add_after event.   please check reference
>   [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251553/magento-2-set-custom-price-in-product-when-add-to-cart)

**2**. If you want do more stuff !! i am suggesting

[**Product Price Formula for Magento Extension**](https://www.itoris.com/magento-2-product-price-formula.html)

> hope it may help

Comment: I know about this extension. But my  query is regarding the process to override cart page

Comment: did you tried with event checkout_cart_product_add_after ?

Comment: I am a newbie in Magento. It would really great help if you could provide any reference for it.

Comment: please try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251553/magento-2-set-custom-price-in-product-when-add-to-cart

Comment: Thx for your help

Comment: i have edited answer please check